# Pass value in php

Tags: php, sql

hi I have modules as a links in student page so after click on any one of these links i want to pass the id of the Specific module to the next page,so how can i pass the id value and this is my code, please help.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MODULE,USER where user_access_level = module_level AND '$user_id' = user_login ";
$result = $db->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li><a href="Personal.php?id=".$G['module_id']."\">'.$row["module_id"].'  '.$row["module_name"].' '.$row["module_points"].'</a></li> ';
    }
}
```

Comment: `AND '$user_id' = user_login` - `user_login` is treated as a constant. Checking for errors would have told you that. Same for `module_level`

Comment: In fact, the logic looks *backwards*

Comment: So much bad quoting and lack of back ticking.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Mah dawg's got a better hang with ticks, on his back.

Comment: @JohnConde Maybe they like going backwards rather than frontwards; some swing that way, just to be different.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe he comes from Arabia, so they read from right to left :D

Comment: AND '$user_id' = user_login, don't you mean user_login = $user_id ?

Comment: @Rizier123 So does the Arabic language ;-)

Comment: [Yoda conditionals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) my young Jedi warriors, eh @Fred-ii-? ;-) I use them all of the time but I know for sure they do not work in SQL statements.

Comment: If only Yoda were *my fah-thah* @JayBlanchard I could just whip out code like there was no tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

Here is your code with all of the quotes, concatenations, backticks and backward logic corrected:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `MODULE`, `USER` WHERE `user_access_level` = 'module_level' AND `user_login` = '". $user_id."' ";
$result = $db->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li><a href="Personal.php?id="'.$G['module_id'].'"\">'.$row["module_id"].'  '.$row['module_name'].' '.$row['module_points'].'</a></li> ';
    }
}
```

I would bet that `module_level` is also supposed to be a variable. `$G` looks problematic, what sets the array `$G`? You should replace the `$G` with `$row` if I am reading this correctly.

Comment: *"what sets the array `$G`?"* - Probably an unshown `while` *Sam* ;-)

Comment: *Tragically* "Hip" ;-) But New Orleans isn't really sinking.

Comment: *"You should replace the `$G` with `$row` if I am reading this correctly."* - Yeah, if the OP isn't pulling `$G` from anywhere else, that would make more sense. *You code detective, you* ;-)

Comment: Actually Jay; yes I do remember an episode where he did, but can't remember which one it was. I think there was a pretty lady involved; probably why. Isn't it "Jake"?

Comment: Maybe, *close... but no cigar*

Answer (score 0):

```
...AND user_id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string ($user_login)."'";
```

I assume?
Anyway, DB_field = $param. And maybe mysql_, not mysqli_, but hope you check the user input before you pass it to the query...

Comment: Maybe he checked it while checking the form values?

Comment: He is better do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax error:

```
echo '<li><a href="Personal.php?id="' . $G["module_id"] . '">' . $row["module_id"] . '  ' . $row["module_name"] . ' ' . $row["module_points"] . '</a></li>';
```